# Cannot manage to update tree cell/item graphics while waiting for a load to complete

Tags: java, javafx, java-8, javafx-8

The initial situation is like this:

[image: initial situation]

Now, the tree is potentially huge (I have a tree with 22 million nodes for instance). What happens here is that I use a jooq/h2 backend to store all the nodes and execute queries to find children.

Which means, in the image above, the node is marked as expandable but its children are not populated yet. It is done on demand. And after expansion I get this:

[image: after expansion]

The problem I have is that of course, expansion can take time; and what I'd like to do is to add a visual clue to the graphic of the `TreeItem` to show that it is loading...

And I can't do it.

---

OK, first of all, a general view of the architecture:

- it is, in short, "MVP with passive views";
- what JavaFX calls a "controller", which is in my code implemented by `*Display` classes, are the passive views, whose only role is to capture UI events and forward them to the `*Presenter`; such classes are "GUI implementation specific";
- the `*Presenter` reacts to those events by ordering the `*View` class to update the `*Display`;
- when tasks require a certain amount of time to complete, too much for the GUI to remain interactive, a `BackgroundTaskRunner` is used by the `*Presenter` to:

  1. instruct the `*View` to modify the UI to acknowledge the task (on the GUI thread);
  2. perform the task (on a background thread);
  3. instruct the `*View` to modify the UI when the task completes (on the GUI thread);
  4. if the task fails, instruct the `*View` to modify the UI accordingly (on the GUI thread).

With JavaFX:

- the UI is a `*Display` class; it is defined by, and loaded from, an FXML file;
- the (implementation of) the `*View` class has visibility over all GUI elements defined in the `*Display` class.

The `*View` class is in fact an interface; this allows me to be able to make a webapp version of this program (planned).

---

Now, the context of this code...

The `*Presenter`, `*View` and `*Display` all relate to the "Parse tree" tab visible in the above images.

Given the architecture above, the problem lies with the implementation of the `*View` class, and with the `*Display` class.

The `*Display` class has an `init()` method which initializes all relevant JavaFX components, if need be. In this case, the `TreeView`, called `parseTree`, is initialized as such:

```
@Override
public void init()
{
    parseTree.setCellFactory(param -> new ParseTreeNodeCell(this));
}
```

`ParseTreeNodeCell` is defined as such:

```
public final class ParseTreeNodeCell
    extends TreeCell<ParseTreeNode>
{
    // FAILED attempt at showing a progress indicator...
    private final ProgressIndicator indicator = new ProgressIndicator();
    private final Text text = new Text();
    private final HBox hBox = new HBox(text, indicator);

    public ParseTreeNodeCell(final TreeTabDisplay display)
    {
        // FIXME: not sure about the following line...
        indicator.setMaxHeight(heightProperty().doubleValue());
        // ... But this I want: by default, not visible
        indicator.setVisible(false);

        // The whole tree is readonly
        setEditable(false);

        // Some non relevant code snipped away
    }

    public void showIndicator()
    {
        indicator.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void hideIndicator()
    {
        indicator.setVisible(false);
    }

    // What to do when a TreeItem is actually attached...
    @Override
    protected void updateItem(final ParseTreeNode item, final boolean empty)
    {
        super.updateItem(item, empty);
        if (empty) {
            setGraphic(null);
            return;
        }
        final String msg = String.format("%s (%s)",
            item.getRuleInfo().getName(),
            item.isSuccess() ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE");
        text.setText(msg);
        setGraphic(hBox);
        // HACK. PUKE. UGLY.
        ((ParseTreeItem) getTreeItem()).setCell(this);
    }
}
```

`ParseTreeItem` is this:

```
public final class ParseTreeItem
    extends TreeItem<ParseTreeNode>
{
    private final boolean leaf;

    private ParseTreeNodeCell cell;

    public ParseTreeItem(final TreeTabDisplay display,
        final ParseTreeNode value)
    {
        super(value);
        leaf = !value.hasChildren();

        // If the item is expanded, we load children.
        // If it is collapsed, we unload them.
        expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue)
            {
                if (oldValue == newValue)
                    return;
                if (!newValue) {
                    getChildren().clear();
                    return;
                }
                display.needChildren(ParseTreeItem.this);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf()
    {
        return leaf;
    }

    public void setCell(final ParseTreeNodeCell cell)
    {
        this.cell = cell;
    }

    public void showIndicator()
    {
        cell.showIndicator();
    }

    public void hideIndicator()
    {
        cell.hideIndicator();
    }
}
```

Now, always in the `*Display` class, the `needChildren()` method is defined as such:

```
ParseTreeItem currentItem;

// ...

public void needChildren(final ParseTreeItem parseTreeItem)
{
    // Keep a reference to the current item so that the *View can act on it
    currentItem = parseTreeItem;
    presenter.needChildren(currentItem.getValue());
}
```

The presenter does this:

```
public void needChildren(final ParseTreeNode value)
{
    taskRunner.computeOrFail(
        view::waitForChildren, () -> {
            // FOR TESTING
            TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1L);
            return getNodeChildren(value.getId());
        },
        view::setTreeChildren,
        throwable -> mainView.showError("Tree expand error",
            "Unable to extend parse tree node", throwable)
    );
}
```

(see [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/79154/21352); for the `taskRunner`)

The corresponding methods in the `view` member above (JavaFX implementation) do this:

```
@Override
public void waitForChildren()
{
    // Supposedly shows the indicator in the TreeItemGraphic...
    // Except that it does not.
    display.currentItem.showIndicator();
}

@Override
public void setTreeChildren(final List<ParseTreeNode> children)
{
    final List<ParseTreeItem> items = children.stream()
        .map(node -> new ParseTreeItem(display, node))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    // This works fine
    display.currentItem.getChildren().setAll(items);
    // But this does not...
    display.currentItem.hideIndicator();
}
```

Even though I define methods on the `TreeItem` to show the progress indicator, it doesn't show at all :/

In fact, my problem is twofold, and all related to `ParseTreeItem`:

- in `ParseTreeNodeCell`, I need to cast to `ParseTreeItem` to set the cell;
- even when I do this, well, it doesn't work at all, I can't see the indicator show up at all.

Not only that, but for some reason I need to check (in `ParseTreeNodeCell`) that I actually have a value, since otherwise I get an NPE. And I can't find a way to get the matching cell from a tree item...

So, all in all, I do many things badly and none correctly.

How do I manage to get the graphic of a `TreeItem` change in that situation, as long as the loading is still in progress?

---

**EDIT**

Solution found, inspited by the code written by @James_D; see my own answer for how I really did it.

Comment: Woof, that is a serious amount of code and waay beyond an MCVE ;-) If you do not mind, I can write a general answer but you will have to adapt it to your needs.

Comment: @eckig Didn't mean to jump in with the same idea, but I was already working on an example when you commented...

Comment: @eckig well, I admit that I didn't fully explain the mechanism; I'll edit my question accordingly...

Comment: @eckig question edited; meh, it's an even _longer_ read than it originally was... Sorry...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First, I admit I didn't go through all your code carefully.

I think the approach to have here is to use a `TreeItem` subclass that exposes an observable property describing the "loaded status" of the children. Then have the tree cells observe the loaded status of the current tree item, and display a progress bar accordingly.

Here's a SSCCE:

(**Updated**: apparently if I only observe the `treeItem` and not the `item`, the tree fails to remove the disclosure graphics from empty cells... Fixed by using the `itemProperty` to manage the text.)

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.ObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleObjectProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;



public class LazyTreeCellLoadingExample extends Application {

    // Executor for background tasks:        
    private static final ExecutorService exec = Executors.newCachedThreadPool(r -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t ;
    });

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeView<Long> tree = new TreeView<>();
        tree.setRoot(new LazyTreeItem(1L));

        // cell factory that displays progress bar when item is loading children:
        tree.setCellFactory(tv ->  {

            // the cell:
            TreeCell<Long> cell = new TreeCell<>();

            // progress bar to display when needed:
            ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();

            // listener to observe *current* tree item's child loading status:
            ChangeListener<LazyTreeItem.ChildrenLoadedStatus> listener = (obs, oldStatus, newStatus) -> {
                if (newStatus == LazyTreeItem.ChildrenLoadedStatus.LOADING) {
                    cell.setGraphic(progressBar);
                } else {
                    cell.setGraphic(null);
                }
            };

            // listener for tree item property
            // ensures that listener above is attached to current tree item:
            cell.treeItemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {

                // if we were displaying an item, (and no longer are...),
                // stop observing its child loading status:
                if (oldItem != null) {
                    ((LazyTreeItem) oldItem).childrenLoadedStatusProperty().removeListener(listener);
                }

                // if there is a new item the cell is displaying:
                if (newItem != null) {

                    // update graphic to display progress bar if needed:
                    LazyTreeItem lazyTreeItem = (LazyTreeItem) newItem;
                    if (lazyTreeItem.getChildrenLoadedStatus() == LazyTreeItem.ChildrenLoadedStatus.LOADING) {
                        cell.setGraphic(progressBar);
                    } else {
                        cell.setGraphic(null);
                    }

                    // observe loaded status of current item in case it changes 
                    // while we are still displaying this item:
                    lazyTreeItem.childrenLoadedStatusProperty().addListener(listener);
                } 
            });

            // change text if item changes:
            cell.itemProperty().addListener((obs, oldItem, newItem) -> {
                if (newItem == null) {
                    cell.setText(null);
                    cell.setGraphic(null);
                } else {
                    cell.setText(newItem.toString());
                }
            });

            return cell ;
        });

        Button debugButton = new Button("Debug");
        debugButton.setOnAction(evt -> {
            dumpData(tree.getRoot(), 0);
        });

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(tree, null, null, debugButton, null), 400, 250));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private void dumpData(TreeItem<Long> node, int depth) {
        for (int i=0; i<depth; i++) System.out.print(" ");
        System.out.println(node.getValue());
        for (TreeItem<Long> child : node.getChildren()) dumpData(child, depth+1);
    }

    // TreeItem subclass that lazily loads children in background
    // Exposes an observable property specifying current load status of children
    public static class LazyTreeItem extends TreeItem<Long> {

        // possible load statuses:
        enum ChildrenLoadedStatus { NOT_LOADED, LOADING, LOADED }

        // observable property for current load status:
        private final ObjectProperty<ChildrenLoadedStatus> childrenLoadedStatus = new SimpleObjectProperty<>(ChildrenLoadedStatus.NOT_LOADED);

        public LazyTreeItem(Long value) {
            super(value);
        }

        // getChildren() method loads children lazily:
        @Override
        public ObservableList<TreeItem<Long>> getChildren() {
            if (getChildrenLoadedStatus() == ChildrenLoadedStatus.NOT_LOADED) {
                lazilyLoadChildren();
            }
            return super.getChildren() ;
        }

        // load child nodes in background, updating status accordingly:
        private void lazilyLoadChildren() {

            // change current status to "loading":
            setChildrenLoadedStatus(ChildrenLoadedStatus.LOADING);
            long value = getValue();

            // background task to load children:
            Task<List<LazyTreeItem>> loadTask = new Task<List<LazyTreeItem>>() {

                @Override
                protected List<LazyTreeItem> call() throws Exception {
                    List<LazyTreeItem> children = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        children.add(new LazyTreeItem(10*value + i));
                    }

                    // for testing (loading is so lazy it falls asleep)
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    return children;
                }

            };

            // when loading is complete:
            // 1. set actual child nodes to loaded nodes
            // 2. update status to "loaded"
            loadTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                super.getChildren().setAll(loadTask.getValue());
                setChildrenLoadedStatus(ChildrenLoadedStatus.LOADED);
            });

            // execute task in backgroun
            exec.submit(loadTask);
        }

        // is leaf is true only if we *know* there are no children
        // i.e. we've done the loading and still found nothing
        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return getChildrenLoadedStatus() == ChildrenLoadedStatus.LOADED && super.getChildren().size()==0 ;
        }

        // normal property accessor methods:

        public final ObjectProperty<ChildrenLoadedStatus> childrenLoadedStatusProperty() {
            return this.childrenLoadedStatus;
        }

        public final LazyTreeCellLoadingExample.LazyTreeItem.ChildrenLoadedStatus getChildrenLoadedStatus() {
            return this.childrenLoadedStatusProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setChildrenLoadedStatus(
                final LazyTreeCellLoadingExample.LazyTreeItem.ChildrenLoadedStatus childrenLoadedStatus) {
            this.childrenLoadedStatusProperty().set(childrenLoadedStatus);
        }


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

**Update**

After quite a bit of discussion, I came up with a second solution. This is basically similar to the previous solution in the way it manages the progress bar: there is a `TreeItem` subclass that exposes a `BooleanProperty` which is true if and only if the item is currently loading its children. The `TreeCell` observes this property on the `TreeItem` it is currently displaying - taking care to register a listener with the `treeItemProperty` so that the listener for the `loadingProperty` is always registered with the current item.

The difference is in the way the children are loaded, and - in the case of this solution - unloaded. In the previous solution, child nodes were loaded when first requested, and then retained. In this solution, child nodes are loaded when the node is expanded, and then removed when the node is collapsed. This is handled with a simple listener on the `expandedProperty`.

The first solution behaves slightly more as expected from a user perspective, in that if you collapse a node which is the head of a subtree, and then expand it again, the expanded state of the subtree is retained. In the second solution, collapsing a node has the effect of collapsing all descendent nodes (because they are actually removed).

The second solution is more robust for memory usage. This is actually unlikely to be an issue outside of some extreme use cases. `TreeItem` objects are purely model - i.e. they store only data, no UI. Thus they probably use no more than a few hundred bytes of memory each. In order to consume significant amounts of memory, the user would have to navigate through hundreds of thousands of nodes, which would probably take days. (That said, I'm typing this into Google Chrome, which I think I've had running for over a month with at least 8-10 hours' active use per day, so such use cases are certainly not impossible.)

Here's the second solution. One note: I don't make any effort to handle a quick expand and collapse of a node (collapsing while the data are still loading). The `TreeItem` subclass should really keep track of any current `Task` (or use a `Service`) and call `cancel()` if a task is running and the user collapses the node. I didn't want to confuse the logic more than necessary to demonstrate the basic idea.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.beans.property.BooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.property.SimpleBooleanProperty;
import javafx.beans.value.ChangeListener;
import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.concurrent.Task;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ProgressBar;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeItem;
import javafx.scene.control.TreeView;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class LazyTreeCellLoadingExample2 extends Application {

    private static final ExecutorService EXEC = Executors.newCachedThreadPool((Runnable r) -> {
        Thread t = new Thread(r);
        t.setDaemon(true);
        return t ;
    });

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TreeView<Integer> tree = new TreeView<>();
        tree.setRoot(new LazyTreeItem(1));

        tree.setCellFactory(tv -> createTreeCell()) ;

        primaryStage.setScene(new Scene(new BorderPane(tree), 450, 600));
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    private TreeCell<Integer> createTreeCell() {

        ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
        TreeCell<Integer> cell = new TreeCell<>();

        ChangeListener<Boolean> loadingChangeListener = 
                (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> obs, Boolean wasLoading, Boolean isNowLoading) -> {
                   if (isNowLoading) {
                       cell.setGraphic(progressBar);
                   } else {
                       cell.setGraphic(null);
                   }
                };

        cell.treeItemProperty().addListener( 
                (ObservableValue<? extends TreeItem<Integer>> obs, 
                        TreeItem<Integer> oldItem, 
                        TreeItem<Integer> newItem) -> {

                if (oldItem != null) {
                    LazyTreeItem oldLazyTreeItem = (LazyTreeItem) oldItem ;
                    oldLazyTreeItem.loadingProperty().removeListener(loadingChangeListener);
                }

                if (newItem != null) {
                    LazyTreeItem newLazyTreeItem = (LazyTreeItem) newItem ;
                    newLazyTreeItem.loadingProperty().addListener(loadingChangeListener);

                    if (newLazyTreeItem.isLoading()) {
                        cell.setGraphic(progressBar);
                    } else {
                        cell.setGraphic(null);
                    }
                }
        });

        cell.itemProperty().addListener(
                (ObservableValue<? extends Integer> obs, Integer oldItem, Integer newItem) -> {
                   if (newItem == null) {
                       cell.setText(null);
                       cell.setGraphic(null);
                   } else {
                       cell.setText(newItem.toString());
                   }
                });

        return cell ;
    }

    public static class LazyTreeItem extends TreeItem<Integer> {

        private final BooleanProperty loading = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

        private boolean leaf = false ;

        public final BooleanProperty loadingProperty() {
            return this.loading;
        }

        public final boolean isLoading() {
            return this.loadingProperty().get();
        }

        public final void setLoading(final boolean loading) {
            this.loadingProperty().set(loading);
        }


        public LazyTreeItem(Integer value) {
            super(value);

            expandedProperty().addListener((ObservableValue<? extends Boolean>obs,  Boolean wasExpanded,  Boolean isNowExpanded) -> {
                if (isNowExpanded) {
                    loadChildrenLazily();
                } else {
                    clearChildren();
                }
            });
        }

        @Override
        public boolean isLeaf() {
            return leaf ;
        }

        private void loadChildrenLazily() {

            setLoading(true);

            int value = getValue();
            Task<List<TreeItem<Integer>>> loadTask = new Task<List<TreeItem<Integer>>>() {

                @Override
                protected List<TreeItem<Integer>> call() throws Exception {
                    List<TreeItem<Integer>> children = new ArrayList<>();
                    for (int i=0; i<10; i++) {
                        children.add(new LazyTreeItem(value * 10 + i));
                    }
                    Thread.sleep(3000);
                    return children ;
                }

            };

            loadTask.setOnSucceeded(event -> {
                List<TreeItem<Integer>> children = loadTask.getValue();
                leaf = children.size() == 0 ;
                getChildren().setAll(children);
                setLoading(false);
            });

            EXEC.submit(loadTask);
        }

        private void clearChildren() {
            getChildren().clear();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

The "double listener" in for the cell is because we really need to observe a "property of a property". Specifically, the cell has a `treeItem` property, and the tree item has a `loadingProperty`. It's the loading property belonging to the current tree item that we're really interested in. Of course, there are two ways this can change: the tree item changes in the cell, or the loading property changes in the tree item. The [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) framework includes API specifically for observing "properties of properties". If you use EasyBind, you can replace the (30 or so lines of) code

```
ChangeListener<Boolean> loadingChangeListener = ... ;

cell.treeItemProperty().addListener(...);
```

with

```
    ObservableValue<Boolean> loading = EasyBind.select(cell.treeItemProperty())
    // ugly cast still here:
            .selectObject(treeItem -> ((LazyTreeItem)treeItem).loadingProperty());

    loading.addListener((obs, wasLoading, isNowLoading) -> {
        if (isNowLoading != null && isNowLoading.booleanValue()) {
            cell.setGraphic(progressBar);
        } else {
            cell.setGraphic(null);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Well, I had something similar in mind but was not ready.. you are faster ;-)

Comment: Hmm, so, the general idea here seems to be to add a listener to the `treeItemProperty()` which I didn't even know existed, huh? I'll try and adapt. In the meanwhile I'll edit my question with the general idea of the design. But as I suck at diagrams it will be a text explanation only, sorry!

Comment: OK, I've spent the last few minutes editing my question and you spent them wirting code, so I'll look at your code carefully again ;) If the edited question can help you understand the design and provide further hints, I will of course welcome them :p

Comment: In your listener, I see that you explicitly remove the listener from the old item; do you mean that if you don't, the old item cannot be garbage collected? To be honest I'm a little confused right now...

Comment: Hmwell, the `TreeView` in itself is not editable in my case; all `TreeItem`s are injected programmatically. So, should I really care about this situation?

Comment: Uhwait, isn't that `expandedProperty()` from the `TreeItem` itself? If yes I already handle that...

Comment: OK, wait. What happens with my code right now is that the node will _not_ get expanded unless children are loaded. Which means the user will not even be able to _select_ a "child node" unless the load completes. I'm afraid I don't follow you.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/70174/discussion-between-fge-and-james-d).

Comment: I am still trying and adapting the code; however it differs fundamentally from one of my core principles, in that it is the expandedProperty() of the TreeItem which drives the fact that the progress indicator should show at all :/

Comment: Added a second solution... I included types in the lambdas in case that helps some; using inner classes would just make it way too verbose imho.

Comment: @James_D well, I have solved my problem; see my own answer. Nevertheless I'll read your code carefully, since I will probably learn a lot from it! GUIs are _hard_

Comment: Well, your second solution has the same problem as the first has; it uses JavaFX specific classes for background task handling. I avoid that at all costs ;) Anyway, thanks for showing me the way to solve it! I just wish I didn't have to do _that_ cast which bothers me... But I guess that it cannot be avoided....

Comment: You can easily use your `BackgroundTaskRunner` in place of the `javafx.concurrent.Task` class, though, if you prefer. The cast cannot be avoided (at least not in any way you'd consider viable) as the use of `TreeItem` is hard-coded into the `TreeView` class. (It would have had to have been `TreeView<S extends TreeItem<T>>` or something, so that you could parametrize the type of `TreeItem` as well as the type of it's value. At some point I guess they have to keep it easy to do the simple stuff...).

Comment: @fge just curious: it's not the creation of the TreeItems that's costly, it's the creation of the ParseTreeNode? If so, why not have a loading (or parsing) property on the value? Assuming that the TreeNode knows about its own hierarchical structure and the TreeItem is just a wrapper around for the sake of fx

Comment: @kleopatra sorry, I don't understand what you mean. And apart from the `leafProperty()` problem you mentioned, I've discovered that my implementation was buggy anyway (children don't "disappear" from the graphics when I collapse the node).

Comment: @fge ParseTreeNode is the value and represents a sub-tree? So it has children? And the parsing/loading of those children is what takes some time? If so, could you move the waitingForChildren into the parseTreeNode thus getting rid of the cast? Update: doooh ... looking closer at your screenshot, it seems like the treeItem creation is the performance bottleneck (you know the nodes and depth right from the start)... if so, just ignore my comments here - will delete once you read it ;-)

Comment: Accepting this answer, even though I don't reuse the code as is. After all, it is this code which got me started! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Problem SOLVED!

Here is how I solved it...

The first thing that I learned with this question is that a `TreeCell` is in fact a "moving object": it moves from `TreeItem` to `TreeItem`; here, the `TreeItem` is a `ParseTreeItem` which has a dedicated property, `loadingProperty()`, and in the cell's `treeItemProperty()` I make use of this property to update the graphics.

As @James_D suggested in his code, I use [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind); the code is basically a ripoff of his, except for the fact that I don't use the cell's text but only a graphic, which is a `HorizontalBox`.

In addition I also have to listen to the cell's `selectedProperty()` since when it is selected, I need to update the info box and the text area:

```
public final class ParseTreeNodeCell
    extends TreeCell<ParseTreeNode>
{
    private final Text text = new Text();
    private final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar();
    private final HBox hBox = new HBox(text);

    public ParseTreeNodeCell(final TreeTabDisplay display)
    {
        setEditable(false);

        selectedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @SuppressWarnings("AutoUnboxing")
            @Override
            public void changed(
                final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue)
            {
                if (!newValue)
                    return;
                final ParseTreeNode node = getItem();
                if (node != null)
                    display.parseTreeNodeShowEvent(node);
            }
        });

        final ObservableValue<Boolean> loading
            = EasyBind.select(treeItemProperty())
            .selectObject(item -> ((ParseTreeItem) item).loadingProperty());

        loading.addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue)
            {
                final ObservableList<Node> children = hBox.getChildren();
                if (newValue == null || !newValue.booleanValue()) {
                    children.remove(progressBar);
                    return;
                }

                if (!children.contains(progressBar))
                    children.add(progressBar);
            }
        });

        itemProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<ParseTreeNode>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                final ObservableValue<? extends ParseTreeNode> observable,
                final ParseTreeNode oldValue, final ParseTreeNode newValue)
            {
                if (newValue == null) {
                    setGraphic(null);
                    return;
                }
                text.setText(String.format("%s (%s)",
                    newValue.getRuleInfo().getName(),
                    newValue.isSuccess() ? "SUCCESS" : "FAILURE"));
                setGraphic(hBox);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Now, the code of `ParseTreeItem` which extends `TreeItem<ParseTreeNode>`, is as such:

```
public final class ParseTreeItem
    extends TreeItem<ParseTreeNode>
{
    private final BooleanProperty loadingProperty
        = new SimpleBooleanProperty(false);

    private final boolean leaf;

    public ParseTreeItem(final TreeTabDisplay display,
        final ParseTreeNode value)
    {
        super(value);
        leaf = !value.hasChildren();
        expandedProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Boolean>()
        {
            @Override
            public void changed(
                final ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> observable,
                final Boolean oldValue, final Boolean newValue)
            {
                if (!newValue) {
                    getChildren().clear();
                    return;
                }
                display.needChildren(ParseTreeItem.this);
            }
        });
    }

    public BooleanProperty loadingProperty()
    {
        return loadingProperty;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isLeaf()
    {
        return leaf;
    }
}
```

Again, this is nearly a ripoff, except for the fact that I don't want the item to hold the logic to:

- fetch the children,
- updating its own loading property.

The "secret" is in `display.needChildren(ParseTreeItem.this)`; this is what it does:

```
public void needChildren(final ParseTreeItem parseTreeItem)
{
    currentItem = parseTreeItem;
    presenter.needChildren(currentItem.getValue());
}
```

And, in turn, the code in `presenter` does:

```
public void needChildren(final ParseTreeNode value)
{
    taskRunner.computeOrFail(
        view::waitForChildren,
        () -> getNodeChildren(value.getId()),
        view::setTreeChildren,
        throwable -> mainView.showError("Tree expand error",
            "Unable to extend parse tree node", throwable)
    );
}
```

And is where the `view` comes in; it is the `view` which updates `currentItem`, since it has direct access to the display and its fields:

```
@Override
public void waitForChildren()
{
    display.currentItem.loadingProperty().setValue(true);
}

@Override
public void setTreeChildren(final List<ParseTreeNode> children)
{
    final List<ParseTreeItem> items = children.stream()
        .map(node -> new ParseTreeItem(display, node))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    display.currentItem.getChildren().setAll(items);
    display.currentItem.loadingProperty().setValue(false);
}
```

As you can see, when `waitingForChildren()` and `setTreeChildren()` update the `loadingProperty()`; and in turn the `ParseTreeNodeCell` will then update the graphics accordingly.

Comment: allow me a couple of comments, unrelated to your problem: a) the leafness is an illegal implementation as it violates the constraint assertEquals(isLeaf, leafProperty.get) - nothing much you can do about it, due to super not supporting semantic leafs b) normally, changelisteners aren't notified if oldValue == newValue (actually, they aren't even for oldValue.equals(newValue)) - if they are in your context, something fishy might go on

Comment: @kleopatra I didn't know about that constraint... I'll fix the code accordingly

Comment: actually, you can't because 1. leafProperty is only privately mutable 2. TreeItem privately mutates it on receiving changes from the children list - It's a missing piece in TreeItem api, hot needle design by oversimplification (Note to self: go ahead and file a bug report ;-)

Comment: They should have made `leafProperty()` non-final and `isLeaf()` final, instead of the other way around... too late now to fix it. I guess the best they can do is make both non-final.

Comment: @James_D wouldn't really help in itself, due to bullet 2 (the property is private and is privately mutated in the base class) To me it looks like they didn't really think about the "semantic" leafness at the start (requires an additional property allowsChildren) and tried to rescue by the non final accessor (which is incorrectly implemented in their example in the api doc). And indeed, nasty to fix in hind-sight: leaf's setter must be protected _and_ leaf's internal update in the change listener extracted into a protected method.

Comment: Yes, thinking more about it that's right. But "how they should have done it" is a moot point now, I guess.

Comment: Something is bothering me about this solution... The cell doesn't observe the `loadingProperty()`, just the `treeItemProperty()`. So you are relying on the tree item changing in order to update the graphic. That might happen when you expand/collapse the item, but it would just be an implementation detail of cell reuse (so it's vulnerable to failure in subsequent versions of JavaFX). Or am I missing something?

Comment: @James_D not sure what you mean; the `loadingProperty()` in fact does not need to be observed at all. As I said, the "JavaFX controller" is totally passive, it is the `view` which is in charge of updating both the cell's graphic and the contents.

Comment: How does the display update the cell's graphic? As far as I can see, all it does it set the `loadingProperty()`. Additionally, from the code you showed for the cell implementation, there is no way another class could update the graphic to include the progress bar (the progress bar is private, and there's no public method that does this). The cell's graphic only changes when its `treeItem` property changes, unless I am missing something...

Comment: OK, I'll update with the full code and how it works; will take a few minutes though :)

Comment: I guess there's no need to do that if you're convinced that any time loading is invoked/completes/cancels(?) the cell knows to update its graphic. It's not obvious from the code though. Additionally: it seems unduly complicated. Since the cell itself already has all the information it needs to determine if it needs to display the progress bar (cell has a treeItem, treeItem has a loadingProperty), why involve other players? Why not just keep it all encapsulated in the cell (whose responsibility is, after all, to manage the display of the item).

Comment: Post updated. The reason I do it is that I want what JavaFX calls a "controller" to be totally passive. If you do it as a real "controller" as per the MVC model then the code base cannot be reused for any other GUI medium, which is what I want (I intend to do a webapp version of this app, the only thing I have to reimplement is the display!)

Comment: @James_D post updated; not sure whether the last comment "made it to you"

Comment: Well, I still don't see it. Your presenter and view classes (obviously) don't (and shouldn't) have a reference to the cell. The presenter invokes `waitForChildren()` and `setTreeChildren()` on the view, but all that does is change the value of the tree item's `loadingProperty`. Since the cell doesn't observe the `loadingProperty` nothing in that code is actually causing the cell to update its graphic.

Comment: I think the only reason it is working is as a side-effect of the specific current implementation of the cell reuse mechanism. In particular, it appears that all cells have their tree items set to null and then they are rebuilt when a tree item is expanded. Hence your listener on the tree item property gets invoked, and "sees" the change in the loading property. Similarly, it just happens that the implementation resets the tree item on a cell when the child list of its current tree item changes; so again your listener just happens to be invoked when loading completes.

Comment: Yes, it does. And yes, the view MUST have a reference to `currentItem` for it to work. The presenter, however, doesn't; it is only called by the display. And since the cell "moves" from one item to the other, it updates the graphics accordingly.

Comment: Well then tell me how to do it better; the thing is, the "JavaFX controller" must only ever have a passive role; it will only be able to tell that "I need children". But never take any action on itself. Since it cannot take any role in updating its own rendering anyway... Not in this case at least

Comment: Just do what I did in my cell: observe the `loadingProperty`. You can still implement the listener of the `expanded` property in the tree item any way you choose; all that's required is that you update the `loadingProperty` somewhere. The implementation of loading the child nodes is completely independent of how you update your cell, no?

Comment: Uuh, OK, I think I misunderstood the intent behind your code... For some reason I thought it would be the tree item listening :( OK, I'll try another solution. Would you mind reviewing it later on if I post it on codereviews?

Comment: Yeah, but it should be just a fairly small edit to your cell class. BTW, if you are not averse to a third party library, [EasyBind](https://github.com/TomasMikula/EasyBind) will make the cell implementation cleaner (it will, uh, make it *easier* to *bind* the graphic to the loading property..). I'll update my answer with that solution.

Comment: I may have other such bindings in the future, so easybind it is. Meh, this program already depends on Guava, h2 and jooq :p

Comment: @James_D OK, code updated. It is basically a ripoff of yours. Thanks for making me discover EasyBind!

Comment: Looks correct to me now. You have a provable code path from changes in the tree item's `expandedProperty()` to the code that adds or removes the progress bar as required that depends only on API specifications (not implementations). You didn't have that before. You and I have different code styles (I like to declare variables to the minimal possible scope, for example, and try to avoid using inheritance unless I am changing the public API or its implementation), but that is basically just a matter of consumer choice...

Comment: FWIW (and basically OT), I rarely use JavaFX without EasyBind for anything more than demos. Given the architecture you have, you'd probably be interested in [afterburner.fx](http://afterburner.adam-bien.com/) for future projects.

Comment: @James_D I've had a try with afterburner already but realized that I didn't need it; also, its exception handling is rather poor, which sits badly in my book! (uncaught exceptions show up in an alert box in my app)